# Zend2 Front End + Angularjs Architecture

Tags: angularjs, zend-framework2

I want to create a search engine using angularjs (one page) inside a Zend2 FrontEnd / Zend2 For API Back End.

The best practices for architecture?

Do you know how to combine Angular JS  and Zend ?

Comment: Resolved
1 - Create your zend framework 2 Rest API application 
2 - Create your zend framework 2 Front End
3 - Now You can start with angular
3-A in the layout.phtml load angular modules exemple(angular.js, angular-resource, etc..)
3-B In the Public  folder create Angularjs architecture
App/
.......App/Config.js
.......App/Controllers
.......App/Filters
.......App/Services etc

4- In Module/Application/View/viewName/
Import angular files like this

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->basePath().'/app/js/config.js';?>"></script>

So i include ui-router at same time